# Invoking Action delegate in method parameter

Tags: c#, delegates

Can somebody tell me please how can I invoke delegate from some method parameter? 
Below I show you a pice of my code.

```
    TestMethod(p =>
                {
                    p.Name = "SomeTool";
                    p.Color = Tool.ToolColor.Red;
                    p.GetToolInfo();
                });

    static void TestMethod(Action<Tool> tool)
    {
       //tool.Invoke(); ????
    }
```

```
class Tool
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ToolColor Color { get; set; }

    public enum ToolColor
    {
        Black,
        White,
        Red
    }

    public string GetToolInfo()
    {
        return $"{Name} {Color}";
    }
}
```

Comment: You've named your Action "tool".    Maybe that's where all the confusion started?

Answer (score 1):

Your test method needs a tool.

```
    Tool myTool = new Tool();
    Action<Tool> myAction = p =>
                {
                    p.Name = "SomeTool";
                    p.Color = Tool.ToolColor.Red;
                    p.GetToolInfo();
                };
    TestMethod(myAction, myTool);
    Console.WriteLine(myTool.Name); // prints "SomeTool"
```

```
    static void TestMethod(Action<Tool> action, Tool tool)
    {
       action(tool);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Action<Tool>` = `Method(Tool tool)`
Your delegate matches a method signature. Then you just invoke a method passed as delegate using your parameter. This allow use of different wired of methods that conform to the signature of the delegate

```
static void TestMethod(Action<Tool> method)
{

   method(new Tool());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you are trying to do here, but I'll quickly break down how the `Action` type works.

The Action type acts like a function pointer that can be passed around (basically a delegate with generic syntax). There are actually two kinds of these types: `Func` and `Action`. The difference between `Func` and `Action` is that `Func` has a generic return parameter while an `Action` always returns void.

You invoke the `Action` by using the method calling syntax:

```
void Test(Action action)
{
    action();
}
```

Now the generic parameters are the parameters in the order that they are required in the action.

In your case, you have the following `Action`:

```
Action<Tool>
```

which is eqivalent to this delegate declaration:

```
delegate void Action(Tool tool);
```

So, whenever you want to invoke that method, you have to pass a parameter in that fits the given generic parameter type. The method itself returns nothing.

You would write the following to get the method to execute:

```
void TestMethod(Action<Tool> tool)
{
    tool(new Tool());
}
```

Further reading:

- [Action Delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Func Delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: eek. Just one tiny little confusing bit at the end.  I'd change the parameter name in the last example `Action<Tool> tool` to `Action<Tool> action`.  and then write `action(new Tool());`

Comment: I tried to match the code that was posted in the question, otherwise I would do the same.